# Track the email open rate with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, html-email

I would like to know how to track an email open rate with Google Analytics. Also, can I track the number of calls made through the call button in my HTML email?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know how to track an email open rate with Google
>   Analytics.

Google recently introduced their version of tracking pixel which can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/email). They have given an image path URL that can be used.

```
<img src="https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&..."/>
```

You can add variables and values to the URL to enable a more detailed reporting. Your tracking will be done through Google Analytics where you can generate reports from their dashboard. The dashboard will show real time user interactions with your emails.

> Also, can I track the number of calls made through the call button in
>   my HTML email?

This is not possible in emails. In order for you to track a link, you need tracking on links and if there is tracking on these links then the functionality breaks.

Hope that answers your question.

Cheers